# How do I combine a char with an int in an NSTextField in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstextfield

For example, I have the following code, where `lblPercent` is an `NSTextField`:

```
double Progress = progress( Points);
[lblPercent setIntValue:(Progress)];
```

I set it as integer value so it tosses out the decimal, since for some reason the `NSProgressIndicator` forces me to use a double. Anyway, in the label adjacent to the progress bar, I want it see the number x% with the percent sign next to it.

I tried standard concatenation techniques but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [NSNumberFormatter with the percent style](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-BCIIABFH)

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
// Any other format settings you want
NSString* formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: progress]];
```

Comment: This gave me a rather bizarre number that wasn't what the variable returned for some reason.

Comment: @JonathanWeinraub Using this method to set the field you should use `setStringValue:` on your test field, nt `setIntValue:`

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you, I had final exams.  Anyway, I now understand what you meant.  However, I changed it to what you suggested, the value I get is 600% so the percent sign is there.  However, my data that is being returned should be 6% not 600%.  So far we are making the best progress on this - I think better progress than I did on my exams :-/

Comment: I assume I do this: [lblPercent setStringValue:(formattedNumber)]; because I just realised it isn't that I got padded with zeroes, I got 750% when I gave it data that should had return 1%.

Comment: @JonathanWeinraub percent style will do the multiplying by 100 for you.  formatting 0.06 with percent style should give you 6% because that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[lblPercent setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%",[Progress intValue]]];
```

Comment: This gave me bad receiver type double.

Comment: What about [lblPercent setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%%",Progress]];?

Comment: Ok progress!  I get the error about **no visible @interface for NSTextField declares in the setText**

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *value = lblPercent.text;
[value appendString:@"%"];
[lblPercent setText:value];
```

Comment: This gave me text not found in object of type NSTextField * and also no visible @interface for NSTextfield declares the selector setText

Comment: @JonathanWeinraub: I've edited your question to make it more clear that you are using Cocoa and `NSTextField`, not `UITextField` in iOS. (This answer assumes `lblPercent` is a `UITextField`, and won't work with `NSTextField`).

Comment: @JonathanWeinraub Before your edit, I assumed you were using UILabel as you named it lblPercent.

Comment: @nsgod any ideas on how I can accomplish this now we sorted out the question properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unicode characters` to get the `percent sign`.

i.e.

`double value;`

`myLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%d\u0025", value ]`

[u0025](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25/index.htm) is the unicode character for `'percent sign'`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger percentageProgress = (NSInteger) (Progress * 100);
[lblPercent setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", percentageProgress]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%@",Progress, @"%"];
[lblPercent setStringValue:string];
```

This seems to had worked for me doing it the way I had done it...